# org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not read path and java.nio.FileAccessDeniedException on Android Studio 3.5.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aapt2

Please read carefully. This is not a duplicate. I've spent countless hours searching the internet for the solution to this problem.
It started with android studio 3.3. So i updated android studio to the latest version 3.5.2, and I updated gradle to version 5.4.1 and android gradle plugin to 3.5.2, still the error persists.

When i click on sync project, it syncs successfully, but when i want to run the app, it throws an exception: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'
I ran it with --debug option, and --stacktrace to get more insights.

here is the stacktrace:

org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor.process(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.executeWithServices(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:178)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:154)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:24)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:383)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:247)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:159)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)

```
at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$FileCollectionLeafVisitorImpl.visitCollection(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:241)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitLeafCollections(AbstractFileCollection.java:233)
at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:126)
at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:48)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.snapshotOutputs(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:429)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$2(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:127)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.fireTransformListeners(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:219)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$3(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:117)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:81)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:90)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:194)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:170)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:194)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:54)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4717)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3444)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2193)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2152)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2042)
... 27 more
```

Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\Freeborn.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5bfb0b3279bf9321cb7d837f84317b2f\aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-windows
    ... 56 more

From the above, in the last part, there is a java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException C;\users\freeborn.gradle\caches

I thought that may be the problem. I opened the folder on explorer, and the folder says access denied.
I tried deleting the folder, still it doesn't work. I restarted my computer, still the problem persists. I cannot delete the folder, I cannot change the permission settings for the folder, it says I do not have authority to change the permission settings of the folder, so I cannot claim the ownership.

It seems like I am the only person having this problem.

this is the main problem:

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.

> Failed to transform artifact 'aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.2-5435860)' to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-android-aapt2-binary, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}.
>   org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not read path 'C:\Users\Freeborn.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5bfb0b3279bf9321cb7d837f84317b2f\aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-windows'.

I have tried everything, now I don't know what to do. If i try downgrading gradle versions, it will work temporarily, and later the problem will return.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your gradle cache location to a directory to which you have access (e.g. other drive, a folder on your desktop or in your documents etc). You can do that by setting the GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable to that new location.